# VS on the compile is going to put SQL DB file in bin/debug

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, sql-server-ce

Hi I use SQL Compact DB in  WPF Project. My project hase this folder structure:

- Project_name

  - DB_file
  - bin

    - debug
    - release

Connection string has this format

```
string connStr="DB_file";
```

If I debug WPF app in Visual Studio it also create copy of DB file in debug or release folder.

I would like use only the one DB file, how can I achieve this behavior?

Because if I insert som data in DB, data are inserted in  DB file in debug / release folder.

But If I try read data from DB, I think it try read data from DB file in Projec_folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the app.config for your real connectionstring (what you are showing must be the connection string name), and put an absoloute path there, and exclude the database from your project. See http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/05/faq-why-does-my-changes-not-get-saved.html